# how do I change language in react-i18next

Tags: reactjs, internationalization

First I Initialize i18next inctance

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

const resources = {
  en: {
    translation: {
      'Welcome to React': 'Welcome to React and react'
    }
  },
  de: {
    translation: {
      'Welcome to React': 'Bienvenue à React et react-i18next'
    }
  }
};

i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
  resources,
  lng: 'de',

  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false
  }
});

export default i18n;
```

and then I am using the instance with useTranslation hook in my component

```
import React from 'react'
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next'

import classes from './intro.module.scss'

export default function Intro() {
    const { t, i18n } = useTranslation()
    return (
        <div className={classes.container}>
            <div className={classes.innerContainer}>
            <h1>{t('Welcome to React')}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

so now how do I change the language to **de** from default language I initialized in i18n instance

I have a button on my navbar and I want that when I click on that button the languages should toggle.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try this, pass the language inside the function to invoke different languages.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next'

import classes from './intro.module.scss'

export default function Intro() {
    const { t, i18n } = useTranslation()

     const changeLanguageHandler = (lang) =>
     {
       i18n.changeLanguage("de")
     }



    return (
        <div className={classes.container}>
            <div className={classes.innerContainer}>
            <h1>{t('Welcome to React')}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 9):

In case anyone needs to get the current selected language, this is how you get it

```
const getLanguage = () => i18next.language || window.localStorage.i18nextLng
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find all the informations you need on the documentation of react-i18n:
https://react.i18next.com/legacy-v9/step-by-step-guide#d-let-the-user-toggle-the-language

You need to use the function i18n.changeLanguage() and pass as props the language desired.

Comment: this is really good article too https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-add-localization-to-your-react-app/

Answer (score 0):

Try this to see what language the user is using in their browser,

`const getUserLanguage = () => window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;`

`window.navigator.language` works for most of the modern browsers but to be on the safe side adding `window.navigator.userLanguage`

And this one to change the language, https://github.com/prajun7/react-till-now/blob/main/src/modules/I18n/index.ts#L1

You can play around here, https://prajun7.github.io/react-till-now/
Just change the language in the right side.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question on how to change the language within the i18n instance to propagate changes into react rendering tree.